# Could isset be used in a condition of a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to get rooms that are **not** written already to a residential apartment short: **RA**. So as long array_shift is dragging the rooms out of the array, the loop should count further and it have to check allRARooms if there are still some rooms left for me.

So is that ok to check for **isset** in a **for condition**?

`for($i = 1; count($ra) <= $quantity && isset($this->allRARooms); $i++)`

Comment: You can have any expression there, it will be evaluated as boolean on every iteration.

Comment: This seems like something you could easily test and find out...

Comment: yeah sry, overseen my own code..... wrong variable, sry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

A for loop can be described as such : `for (initialisation; alive condition; last loop statement)`

it can be translated using a `while` loop that way :

```
initialisation
while (alive condition)
{
    // some code

    last loop statement
}
```

You put what you want as long as it respects the differents statements

```
for($i = 1; count($ra) <= $quantity && isset($this->allRARooms); $i++) {  }
```

is equivalent to

```
$i = 1;
while (count($ra) <= $quantity && isset($this->allRARooms))
{
    // some code

    $i++;
}
```

You can add many initialisation and last instruction statements and the alive condition can be independant of them.

```
$aConditionIndependantOfInit = true;
for ($i = 0, $j = 42; $aConditionIndependantOfInit; $i++, $j--)
{
    echo "foo\n";
    if ($i >= $j)
        $aConditionIndependantOfInit = false;
}
```

This output 21 `foo`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set `for` loop terminating condition to whatever expression you like.

You can even skip it ! for example:

```
for ($i=0;;$i++) {
 if ($i>10) break; 
 echo "$i\n";
}
```

Or maybe you want an everlasting loop with `for`? here it is :

```
for (;;) echo ++$x . "\n";
```

In essence you can skip whatever part in for loop you need

#### Condition optimization

Your condition `count($ra) <= $quantity && isset($this->allRARooms)` can be factored a bit.

1. In 99% cases it's enough of `count($ra) <= $quantity && $this->allRARooms`, because `'',null,[]` - all evaluates to `false`.
2. Further you should put *allRARooms* var check at first place, like:
    
   `$this->allRARooms && count($ra) <= $quantity`. In that way you will employ a [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) trick for boosting condition check speed, because if var *allRARooms* is not set - count($ra) will not be evaluated - thus saving CPU ticks

Comment: I was about to add the empty statements in my answer, but you already did it. +1